# Can't Log In With Client Id / Secret Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to use Microsoft Graph API to manage Azure AD B2C users from an application, but I have been unable to authenticate using my client id / secret.

First, I followed the steps here to register an application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga

At the end of that article, I was directed here to learn how to get an access token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token

They suggest using the endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant/oauth2/v2.0/token, but when I use my tenant in that URL, I get the error "Tenant 'mytenant' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator."

Makes sense, that's not the kind of url I've been using anyway.  But what the heck endpoint should I use?  So I tried a few.

There are some endpoint suggestions in my application overview, in the format of
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/policy-name/oauth2/v2.0/token
But what is the policy name?  There was nothing in the instructions about setting up a policy.
I have some user flows that might be what they're talking about, so I tried a few, like
if I use https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in/oauth2/v2.0/token,
I get "The supplied grant_type [client_credentials] is not supported."

There are also endpoints suggested in my workflows, in the format
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_sign_in
This gives the same client_credentials error.

I also tried with a b2c_1_ropc user flow instead of b2c_1_sign_in, with similar results.

What am I doing wrong?  Are the instructions incomplete?  Have I not guessed the appropriate endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your assumed suggestions are incorrect.

The doc says to use the endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant/oauth2/v2.0/token, this is wholly correct.

If your B2C tenant has tenant name contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or contoso.b2clogin.com, then endpoint is https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was a life saver!  Though I don't agree that the docs are "wholly correct", or at least I'd say they're not clear.  How was I supposed to know "mytenant" in this case stood for "contoso.onmicrosoft.com" while they frequently use it to refer to just "contoso"?  I saw no indication in Azure that I should use that endpoint, and the docs weren't clear to me either.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my B2C tenant name (see under Tenant Properties in Azure) was `Company Customers`, so all my user flow endpoints were showing as:

`https://Company Customers.b2clogin.com/mytenantdev.onmicrosoft.com/...`

I had to update the tenant name, removing the space and then re-create my application registration and things started working. I didn't have to redo the user flows however.

So the final endpoints looked something like this: `https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenantdev.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>...`

Should also note, I had to logout of Azure and back in to get the tenant name to start appearing correctly in the console.

Comment: This may not have been necessary.  The endpoints will show up with the spaces in the names, but they work using the real tenant name which doesn't have spaces, at least that's been my experience.  It's still probably cleaner the way you did it though.  And it's a good tip.